# Why is json_encode returning null?

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

i am new in PHP. My problem is null pointer returned by json_encode. I am trying to get data from mysql database on mamp server. What am I doing wrong?? I should use something like utf8_encode?? I've tried, nothing special happenend This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $database = "authors";

    $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if (!$db){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM names";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        print_r( $resultArray );
        $s = json_encode($resultArray);
        echo $s;
        if( $s = NULL )
        {
            echo "Nullpointer";
        }
        elseif( $s == "" )
        {
            echo "Empty string";
        }
    }

    $db->close();
?>
```

And it is the output:

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Johny
            [LastName] => Mielony 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Will
            [LastName] => Turner
        )
  )

Empty string
```

---

Updated code:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $database = "authors";

    $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    if (!$db){
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM names";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        print_r( $resultArray );
        $s = json_encode($resultArray);
        echo $s;
        if( $s == false )
        {
            echo "Nullpointer";
        }
        elseif( $s == "" )
        {
            echo "Empty string";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "It's gooood";
        }
    }

    $db->close();
?>
```

and output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Adrian
            [LastName] => Kaczmarek
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Krzysztof
            [LastName] => Rózga
        )

)
Nullpointer
```

Comment: `if( $s = NULL )` should be a `==` here instead

Comment: @Adrian [RT(F)M](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). json_encode NEVER returns `NULL`. It returns a string, or FALSE.

Comment: fix this first, it might change a lot of things :) by doing so you're erasing the $s value as well as corrupting your tests logic.

Comment: output is:Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Adrian
            [LastName] => Kaczmarek
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [FirstName] => Krzysztof
            [LastName] => Rózga
        )

)
Nullpointer

Comment: update your question with that output. As you see it doesn't format well in the comments.

Comment: Do View Source if you are looking at it in the browser, or execute it otherwise in a way that make the output available in plain text.

Comment: i have changed this '==', but result is first 'if'statement

Comment: Do `var_dump( $s );`. You'll probably see that it is, in fact, FALSE and not an empty string, nor null. It is impossible to get NULL back from `json_encode`. I don't know which input would generate the empty string.

Comment: $s == null and $s == "" is the same as $s == false. See strict equals (=== vs. ==)

Comment: "ó" - maybe utf-8 problem? Please enable error_reporting() and display-errors. Your json_encode() should raise a warning.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try to solve problem

1. Explore errors

   ```
   echo json_last_error();
   echo json_last_error_msg();
   ```
2. Use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

   ```
   $s = json_encode($resultArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
   ```